# Dropdown list not work with data-native-menu="false"

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu

I use dropdown list with PHP to retrieve data from my sql database, It exists on this [link.](http://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/php/5568/creating-dependent-dropdown-list-php-jquery-and-ajax.html)

It worked well but when I change  the menu style what I want, does not work.
this menu code is what I want:

```
    <select name="parent_cat" id="parent_cat" data-native-menu="false" class="filterable-select" data-iconpos="left">

I think the problem exists because the menu shows in popup : `#&ui-state=dialog` 
but I do not know how to solve this problem.

this full HTML code :
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Dependent DropDown List</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#parent_cat").change(function() {
        $(this).after('<div id="loader"><img src="img/loading.gif" alt="loading subcategory" /></div>');
        $.get('loadsubcat.php?parent_cat=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
            $("#sub_cat").html(data);
            $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }); 
    });

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form method="get">
    <label for="category">Parent Category</label>
    <select name="parent_cat" id="parent_cat" data-native-menu="false" class="filterable-select" data-iconpos="left">

        <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_parent)): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['category_name']; ?></option>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </select>
    <br/><br/>

    <label>Sub Category</label>
    <select name="sub_cat" id="sub_cat"></select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help

Comment: where is jquery and php?

Comment: I want to use the same code found in the link with change add data-native-menu="false" to the select menu

Comment: custom select uses a popup with a listview to display the menu
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/selectmenu-custom/

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you've written, you must include the relevant code in your question itself, not just link to it.

Comment: Please delete this post i will write a new post with the full code